# External Table Template: Bad syntax?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I just installed SQL Express and the Microsoft SSMS. I made my first database! But now I am trying to add an "External Table". I right click under "master\Tables\External Tables" and click "New External Table..."

When I try to execute the template example code, I get a bunch of Incorrect syntax messages.

```
-- ==============================
-- Create External Table Template
-- ==============================
USE <database_name, sysname, AdventureWorks>
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('<schema_name, sysname, dbo>.<table_name, sysname, sample_external_table>', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP EXTERNAL TABLE <schema_name, sysname, dbo>.<table_name, sysname, sample_external_table>
GO

 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE <schema_name, sysname, dbo>.<table_name, sysname, sample_external_table>
(
<column1_name, sysname, c1> <column1_datatype, , int> <column1_nullability, , NOT NULL>,
<column2_name, sysname, c2> <column2_datatype, , char(10)> <column2_nullability, , NULL>,
<column3_name, sysname, c3> <column3_datatype, , datetime> <column3_nullability, , NULL>
)
WITH
(
LOCATION = N'<location, nvarchar(3000), sample_location>',
DATA_SOURCE = <data_source_name, sysname, sample_data_source>,
FILE_FORMAT = <file_format_name, sysname, sample_file_format>,
REJECT_TYPE = <reject_type, nvarchar(20), sample_reject_type>,
REJECT_VALUE = <reject_value, float, sample_reject_value>,
REJECT_SAMPLE_VALUE = <reject_sample_value, float, 
sample_reject_sample_value>
)
GO
```

The Syntax errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? When I mouse over any of the '<' characters it says:

> Incorrect syntax near '<'. Expecting '(', or SELECT.

or

> Incorrect syntax near '<'. Expecting '.',ID, or QUOTED_ID.

Also this line has a different error message

```
USE <database_name, sysname, AdventureWorks>
```

when I mouse over:

> Could not locate entry in sysdatabases for database ''. No entry found with that name. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Comment: That's *example* code.  It's missing lots of stuff you're supposed to supply.  All that angle bracket stuff is essentially "here's a placeholder, it accepts things of this type (lists items in placeholder). You have to replace this placeholder with a value that makes sense for you and your objective."

Comment: Also, the example code contains all optional parameters as well. So this is most likely overwhelming (it would be to me if I didn't know sql). If you are just learning, you may want to start with an example that is much smaller and build on that knowledge. Like `CREATE TABLE Foo (Bar int)` will create a table called Foo with one integer column Bar. Then practice more difficult things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Will has said this is a code template. You need replace all `<....>` with values.

The easiest way to specify values is by opening "Specify Values for Template Parameters.." window accessible from the "Query" menu.

See: [How to: Use Templates in SQL Server Management Studio](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179334(v=sql.105).aspx)